# How to add advertisement in chrome browser extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have seen that google allows extensions to include advertisements (though not with adsense). What I need to know is an example of adding an ad to my extension (i.e. where to get one? how to inject the ad (simply by injecting it in the website's code)?). I am just planning to add only a small ad and let the users know about it (and its position in the site) as well as giving them the option to remove it.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

Comment: All I could find was https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies. I haven't seen any extensions with advertisements yet. I assume you're able to integrate and monetize ads yourself, but they aren't helping directly at this point.